# Invitations not showing up in friend's notification

Tags: facebook, invite, invitation, multi-friend-selector

I have a site that's been integrated with fb for a little while.  Recently we have noticed that invites are not being delivered to users friends.  The multi friend selector shows up fine and the the preview for the message that should show up in their friends message list is correct. But it doesn't actually get delivered.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because the multi friend selector is deprecated. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment. But have you done something with this issue? I have the same situation - invitation were working fine (appearing in users notification alerts). But some day they began to appear in app center requests section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the invite now end up under the 'apps and games' section